# confirmation dialogue on success ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

```
jQuery("#uploadForm").ajaxForm({
    target: '#location'
    success :funcion(){}
}).submit();
```

I am submitting a form as above, and updating a Div. on success I want to show a confirmation dialogue with yes or no . on user response I want to give a ajax call again.

How can I do that.. Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: he has only 2 answers on 7 questions, and in both cases it looks like the needed solution is not found (= no comment like "yes it works"). If there is misunderstanding or unclear asking, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#uploadForm").ajaxForm({
    target: '#location'
    success :function(){
       // show your dialogue
       var response = window.confirm('Yes or NO?');
       if(response) {
          // code for yes

       } else {
          // code for no

       }
    }
}).submit();
```

You can try also this:

```
var options = { 
    target:     '#location', 
    url:        'your_url', 
    success:    function() { 
        alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 
    } 
}; 

jQuery("#uploadForm").ajaxForm(options).submit();
```

Comment: I believe OP wanted a "Yes, No" box, not a message box, if I understood his question

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `confirm` function.

```
jQuery("#uploadForm").ajaxForm({
    target: '#location'
    success: funcion() {
        var result = confirm("OK or cancel?");
        if(result) {
            // User clicked OK
        }
        else {
            // User clicked cancel
        }
    }
}).submit();
```

You can, of course, put any message you'd like into the confirm function

---

Source: [Tizag - Javascript Tutorial - Confirm](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptconfirm.php)

Comment: thank you for you answer. I want confirmation with some message and buttons should be 'yes' or 'no'

Comment: The buttons in the built-in confirm message are "OK" and "Cancel". If you want different buttons you'll have to create your own confirm dialog, or use some plugin.